# Click a Browser Prompt With Any Python Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Basically I am Working with a project in which i got a problem the problem is that, I want to click that prompt shown below:

[image: For Image Click Here]

by not clicking with my physical hand but with python (any module for this or any way)

Comment: What have you done (you can use https://pypi.org/project/mouse/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cancel button has an auto-focus when this window opens. You could send Keys to interact with this message. In this case you would need an "Arrow-Left-Key" and then send "ENTER" / "RETURN". You can archive this by calling native windows-api-functions using this library https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32